# $project Distinct Items in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a very large collection of items in mongodb with a schema that I cannot change. The simplified version looks like this:

```
{event: { address: {ip: "1.1.1.1", port: 80}}}
{event: { address: {ip: "1.1.1.2", port: 80}}}
{event: { address: [{ip: "1.1.1.1", port: 80}, {ip: "1.1.1.1", port: 443}]}}
{event: { address: [{ip: "1.1.1.1", port: 8080}, {ip: "1.1.1.2", port: 443}]}}
```

Each event might have one or more addresses. Each address has both "ip" and "port". So an "ip" might be repeated in an event with several addresses.

All I want to do is to count the number of events for each ip address and find the top ip addresses. For the above example, the preferred result is:

```
[ { "ip" : "1.1.1.1", "count" : 3 },
  { "ip" : "1.1.1.2", "count" : 2 } ]
```

A query that comes to mind is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$project: {ip: "$event.address.ip"}}, {$group: {_id: "$ip", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {count: -1}}, {$limit: 5})
```

But the result is:

```
{
 "result" : [
  { "_id" : ["1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.2"], "count" : 1 },
  { "_id" : ["1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.1"], "count" : 1 },
  { "_id" : "1.1.1.2", "count" : 1 },
  { "_id" : "1.1.1.1", "count" : 1 } ],
 "ok" : 1
}
```

I cannot use $unwind because each IP address should be count only one time for each event, but some of the events have the same IP repeated. Also, $unwind would not work in general because "address" is not always an array. Some of the events have only one address that is not an array and $unwind will throw an exception for them.

I tried different aggregation operators like $addToSet in $group but all to no avail.

The collection is very large and I can't first extract all the ip addresses in my application and then count events for each one.

Can it be done with a map/reduce. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this can be done with MapReduce, Aggregation framework will be faster.  You need to add two steps to your plan - 1) you need to "normalize" the format so that address is always an array, 2) you then need to $unwind that array, group by _id,ip to get rid of duplicates and then group by ip to get the counts you need.

Normalizing arrays and non-arrays is tricky, but it can be done with two projections before and after the `$unwind`.

```
var p1 = { "$project" : {
        "array" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$address.0",
                        [ ]
                    ]
                },
                "$address",
                [
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        "notarray" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$ne" : [
                        "$address.0",
                        [ ]
                    ]
                },
                "$address",
                [
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        "isArray" : {
            "$eq" : [
                "$address.0.ip",
                [ ]
            ]
        }
    }
};
var u = { "$unwind" : "$array" };
var p2 = { "$project" : {
        "address" : {
            "$cond" : [
                "$isArray",
                "$array",
                "$notarray"
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

By comparison, the two `$group` stages are simple:

```
var g1 = { "$group" : { "_id" : { "_id" : "$_id", "ip" : "$address.ip" } } };
var g2 = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.ip", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } };
```

Here is my sample data:

```
> db.coll.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd0badba17f3b7ed212575"), "address" : { "ip" : "1.1.1.1" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd0bc4ba17f3b7ed212576"), "address" : [  {  "ip" : "1.1.1.1" },  {  "ip" : "1.1.1.1" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd0bc9ba17f3b7ed212577"), "address" : [  {  "ip" : "1.1.1.1" },  {  "ip" : "1.1.1.2" } ] }
```

And here is the aggregation and its output:

```
> db.coll.aggregate(p1, u, p2, g1, g2)
{ "_id" : "1.1.1.1", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "1.1.1.2", "count" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah you've got two problems, one being that the schema was not designed well and two that it is not standardised such that the same field does not at least have the same structure. Your between a rock and a hard place.

If all the address fields were all arrays then this would work easily but instead you cannot current conditionally `$unwind`, unfortauntely if you attempt to `$unwind` anything but an array so that you could unwind address then you will get an error:

> If you specify a target field for $unwind that is not an array, db.collection.aggregate() generates an error.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

So yeah, your kind of stuck here.

This can be done with MR but the grouping would be a pain. Personally what I would do is run an incremental MR which writes this schema out in a standardised format so that the aggregation framework can be used on it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky that's a crazy amount of conditionals, are you sure that if the data set grows it will still be faster?

Comment: of course it will be faster - mapreduce would also have to process more documents/fields as the data set grows.  And first project has two conditionals (one in each of two new fields) and second project has one conditional.  That's hardly "crazy"